# Creating AWS SQS Request in Javascript with IAM user

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, hmac, amazon-sqs

I have created an IAM User that has only SendMessage privilege on one SQS queue. I would like to distribute this IAM user's credentials to my client's browser so that messages may be sent to this SQS queue. How can I use these credentials to create a signed request in JavaScript? I have an open source HMAC-SHA256 JS script available, I am just having trouble understanding the documentation on the version 4 signing process and examples are scarce.

I understand cross-domain origin implications and can work around them.

Comment: Have you looked at the version 4 signer in the AWS SDK for Node.js - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/signers/v4.js ?